# vmware workstation Cannot change network to bridged

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, bridged

i'm using vmware workstation 8. I can not bridge my network adapter. I reinstalled a virtual machine and chose Bridged.  When i view Virtual network editor, there is no bridged vmnet. I have NAT vmnet8 and host-only vmnet1, and vmnet0 says Host-only. I changed nic's to a dlink dfe538tx from an onboard Realtek PCIe nic.  I am still getting  this error occured: Cannot change network to bridged: There are no un-bridged host network adapters. Reinstallation of vmware didn't solve the problem either. Any assistance would be appreciated, 
RuRat

Comment: did you apply the changes before creating the bridged adapter?

Comment: I tried creating the bridged adapter after changing nic's and still got the same issue, I have now also tried a dlink dge-530T adapter and still same error.  even with having The Realtek and the dge adapter active it gives me the same error.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: using windows 10 pro insider preview build 10074

Comment: in the virtual machine does it always list the nic as intel pro no matter what the actual nic is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have an answer, but you're not going to like it.

As VMware Workstation 8 is designed to work only on Windows Vista or Windows 7, and Windows 8 support was not introduced until version 9, You have no choice but to upgrade.

Unfortunately, you can no longer get Workstation 9, and Workstation 11 is the only version available to buy, and the only version with Windows 10 support.

Comment: mmm and there is no 32 bit version of vmware 11

Comment: and you shouldn't be using Windows 10 x86 anyway. You might want to think of putting the Windows architecture in your question next time

Comment: ya sorry i failed to mention that so windows 10 doesnt work well in x86?

Comment: It works, just as to whether Windows 10 works well in x86... 64 bit is always favored by software now, including Windows and VMware Workstation